# Hope I'm totally wrong

Tags: discussion

Apparently someone here banished me.  I am the most enthusiastic puzzler around and haven't been on the attack since 1970.  Hope I'm wrong but that's what someone said.

Comment: For those unaware, this was previously [discussed on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381703/579398).

Comment: I see comments in defense.  Thank you!  I know better than to take offense.

Comment: To keep people from having to dig through the other post's comments: this meta question is because the OP is temporarily chat-banned, and suspects that it was a Puzzling mod who did it. The OP feels wrongfully suspended.

Comment: @bobble https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381703/please-take-it-easy#comment1273238_381703 someone told him it was a Puzzling mod (I don't know if it's true), but I think that's the only reason he's posting this here.

Comment: @forest Yes, I know, but the fact they've posted here indicates they suspect it to some extent, and I was trying to simplify the confusing discussion from the other comment thread

Answer (score 6):

(I have not read the other thread mentioned in comments on the question. It is possible that some of what I say here happens to duplicate some of what others said there.)

Chat bans can be handed out by (I think) *any* SE moderator. I am actually not sure what the usual etiquette is around revealing information about who has chat-banned whom when, but I am reasonably comfortable saying that

- yes, whiskrs is currently chat-banned
- but not by a Puzzling moderator.

That doesn't necessarily mean that the ban wasn't provoked by something whiskrs did *in The Sphinx's Lair chat*; any mod might be reading any chatroom, after all. When someone is chat-banned, it is possible for the person who does it to leave a note saying why, but not necessary, and frequently they don't. In this instance they didn't.

Comment: It may be worth noting that [his last message in chat.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10964?m=61887807#61887807) (in the Litter Box, chatrooms for [pets.se]) was followed by one moderator telling him "@whiskrs consider yourself warned for attempting to disrupt chat. Please engage with others here in a constructive manner." and another moderator telling him "@whiskrs so - this has happened before on multiple sites and you've been suspended quite a few times[.] You might want to reconsider your approach to chat"